# SameSite=None not working on Chrome incognito?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, samesite, incognito-mode

I visited this site: https://samesite-sandbox.glitch.me/ both on normal and incognito Chrome window. This happens 100% of the time both on Mac Chrome and Android Chrome. Incognito had no extensions enabled.
Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

Chrome version: 84.0.4147.105

Here's the incognito result:
[image]

Here's the result on non-incognito window:
[image]

Comment: Having the same issue, doesn't make any sense to me... Incognito sets an insecure samesite=none cookie, but refuses to set secure samesite=none one...

Comment: Having same issue

Answer (score 9):

Actually just found the solution
From this site:
https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug

If you are testing in Incognito Mode, be aware that the default setting for Incognito Mode is to block third-party cookies. This can lead to behavior that appears similar to cross-site cookies being blocked due to lack of a SameSite attribute. This setting can be changed on Incognito Mode's New Tab Page, or in chrome://settings/cookies.

Comment: Thank you so much!