# Axios methods GET and POST do not respond in Vercel deploy

Tags: reactjs, node.js, axios, vercel

I have a MERN project in my Vercel account which is divided into two parts: client and server. Both pages are perfectly deployed and available but my Axios methods related to the server page don't work in my deploy when they do in my local PC. The only one that responds correctly is the hero, which brings me six images from my database and renders what I need. However, when I go into another route the browser console throws an error 500. For instance, I am in a route where I have an useEffect hook with an Axios POST method and I have no response from the server.

Axios from the front:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    async function getList(){
      try{
        const response = await axios.post("https://pelis-mern-server-five.vercel.app/lists/get-my-list", {id:user._id, profId:profileId}, {withCredentials:true, headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"}})
        console.log(response)
        if(response.data.list.length > 0){
          console.log("hay")
          setList(response.data.list)
        }
      }catch(err){console.log(err.stack)}
    }
    getList()
  },[])
```

Controller from the back (route /lists/get-my-list):

```
const get_my_list = async (req,res) => {
    console.log("req.user", req.user)
    const {id, profId} = req.body
    const user = await User.findById(id)
    const index = user.profiles.findIndex(prof => prof._id == profId)
    const list = user.profiles[index].myList
    res.json({list:list})
}
```

This is what I obtain in my browser's console (my catch's `console.log(err.stack)`):

```
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500
    at settle.js:19:12
    at XMLHttpRequest.f (xhr.js:111:7)
```

Axios also says that the error is BAD_RESPONSE, not BAD_REQUEST. The same error happens when I go into my dashboard with a GET method in an useEffect.

```
useEffect(()=>{
        async function obtainProfiles(){
            try{
                const data = await axios.get("https://pelis-mern-server-five.vercel.app/profiles",{withCredentials:true})
                console.log(data.data)
                setProfiles(data.data)
            }catch(err){
                console.log(err.stack)
            }
        }
        obtainProfiles()
},[])
```

From the back (route /profiles):

```
const get_all_profiles = async (req,res) => {
  console.log("req.user", req.user)
  let call = await User.findById({_id:req.user.id})
  let profiles = call.profiles
  res.json(profiles)
}
```

I check the logs in my server's deploy and this is the error that appears every time I don't have a response.

```
req.user undefined //user object console log

Unhandled Promise Rejection 
{"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')",
"reason":{"errorType":"TypeError",
"errorMessage":"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')",
"stack":["TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')"," at get_all_profiles 
(/var/task/server/controllers/userControllers.js:68:48)","    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] 
(/var/task/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)","    at next 
(/var/task/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)","    at Route.dispatch 
(/var/task/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)","    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] 
(/var/task/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)","    at /var/task/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15","    at Function.process_params 
(/var/task/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)","    at next 
(/var/task/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)","    at Function.handle 
(/var/task/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:175:3)","    at router 
(/var/task/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)"]},"promise":{},"stack":
["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')","    at process.<anonymous> (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1276:17)","   
at process.emit (node:events:529:35)","    
at emit (node:internal/process/promises:149:20)","   
at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:283:27)","    
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:32)"]}

Unknown application error occurred

Runtime.Unknown
```

I think the main problem here is the user related to Passport's authentication. When I log in, the /signin route's log says that my user is authenticated and shows me the object but disappears when is redirected to the dashboard, making req.user undefined and not authenticated.

Why does this happens on Vercel when in my local host does work perfectly?

This is also my Passport strategy:

```
const passport = require('passport')
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const User = require('../models/User')
const bcrypt=require('bcrypt')

module.exports.start = async(passport)=>{
  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email', 
    passwordField: 'password', 
  },
  async (email, password, done) => {

      try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'User not found' });
        }
         const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        
        if (!isPasswordValid) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Contraseña incorrecta' });
        }else{
          //console.log(user)
           return done(null, user);
        }
  
      } catch (error) {
        return done(error);
      }
    }
  ));
  
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    console.log("serialized", user)
    done(null, user._id);
  });
  
  passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    console.log("deserialized")
    console.log(id)
    try {
      const user = await User.findById({_id : id});
      done(null, user);
    } catch (error) {
      done(error);
    }
  })
}
```

I call it in this way on index.js:

```
const passport = require('passport')
const local = require('./config/passport')
const flash = require('connect-flash')

local.start(passport)
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.use(flash())
```

Comment: There's nothing to debug in this question. How is `req.user` populated? Why do you expect it to have a value?

Comment: In my local code we use the `req.user` to authenticate it with its Passport strategy and save its data (an object that we call and comes from the database) in it. However, once I log my user in my deploy the object that comes from my Mongo db vanishes and req.user ends up as an undefined value on my client page when it should have the database's response.

Comment: Ok, so what is your Express session configuration? To support cross-origin cookies you need `Secure` and `SameSite=None`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't set the SameSite attribute of the cookie to None in Nodejs (Express)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63680921/283366)

Comment: Hi. I tried this and my express-session cookie config has the next properties: `maxAge`, `secure = true`, and `sameSite = "none"`. It still has the same error 500 on my Vercel deploy. The other properties I have on my config are `resave = true`, `saveUninitialized = false`, the store from connect-mongo package and the secret

Comment: This is also my cors config on vercel.json    

 "routes": [{ "src": "/(.*)",
    "dest": "/" , 
    "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"],
    "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://pelis-mern-client-nine.vercel.app"
    }}]

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `console.log(req)`, you will realize that your user is in the `body` attribute.

Just replace `req.user.id` with `req.body.user.id`

Comment: Hi, I tried this and it didn't work. I still have the same problem. I did the same thing using Postman and the answer I received was FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED

Comment: OK, but what do the logs say ? I think it's just another error that happens on another part of your code

Comment: I've tried again today and now it looks like the controller where I wrote `req.body.user.id` works but the others don't. This is the log that appears after a failed attempt: `Unhandled Promise Rejection[...]"errorMessage":"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'myList')"`. myList is a property that comes from my user's model. All of my server errors now are related to the user data not being found.

Comment: Yes, it means that `user.profiles[index]` is `undefined`. Why ? Because the line where you do `user.profiles.findIndex` didn't find a profile with the `_id` equal to `profId` from the body.

You should try to add `console.log(user.profiles)` and `console.log(profId)` to understand why, but I consider this is unrelated to your original question.

Comment: I recently checked this out and profId is a null value on the server. What I don't understand is that this same controller works outside the deploy (in localhost) and the profile's _id from the db gets in the function.